# TypeScript type check inline isn't the same as type check in functions

Tags: typescript, types

I have a strange (to me at least) issue where type checking inline doesn't work the same way as type checking in a function. The exact same check, doesn't work, when extracted to a function.

I've posted a screenshot so you can see the errors, and a [link to same code on Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-type-check-inline-isnt-the-same-as-type-check-in-functions-f6s72).

I first had the issue in IntelliJ but made this isolated issue in CodeSandbox (Visual Studio Code), so I guess the issue is TypeScript.

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

[image: Errors in Code Sandbox]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you need to implement a "type guard":

```
const isPromise = (maybePromise: unknown): maybePromise is Promise<unknown> => {
  return (
    typeof maybePromise === "object" &&
    typeof (maybePromise as Promise<unknown>).then === "function"
  );
};

// Util to tell if argument is a String
const isString = (maybeString: unknown): maybeString is string => {
  return typeof maybeString === "string";
};
```

`maybePromise is Promise<unknown>` and `maybeString is string` [will guarantee the type in the scope.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-8ilugj

Comment: Awesome. Didn't know that. Thank you.